# Flutter Stream print document.length is 0 even there is data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display my data from firestore by using Streambuilder but flutter have problem with reading data.

I was think that the stream build code is problem but it might be not. I have following flutter document way or youtube video way, either not working.

After I have try figure out by using print method, then document.length show 0 !

So I think flutter didn't know there is data even firestore have data

there is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => const PostScreen(),
            ),
          );
        },
        // onPressed: createNewObject,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _firestore
            .collection('Goals')
            .orderBy('timestamp')
            .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('ERROR: ${snapshot.error}');
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            print('Waiting...');
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: lightHoney,
              ),
            );
          }
          print('Connected!');
          List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data!.docs;
          print(documents.length);
          return ListView(
            children: documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              print(document['writer']);
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(document['goalTitle']),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This typically means that:

- The local cache has a snapshot of when there was no data.
- The client is not able to connect to the server to get a new snapshot.

To verify that, try writing a goal to the database from the same client. If that data **does** show up in the client, but **does not** show up in the database, you'll know you're looking at cached data only.

Comment: Thank you for answer! but can you explain more specific ? I can't understand show up in the client meaning. the two goals are written same client in image and writer is also same 'jack@email.com'